# Set Default View for Views For Display Contacts in Advanced Search Form

Tags: profile, search, search-results

I want to change the columns that are shown in the advanced search results.

I have created a Search Views Profile and this shows up in the dropdown list of the Search Views on the Advanced Search Form. This works fine. Is it possible for me to make this Search View Profile the default Search View?

I looked in the admin screen for customising search preferences (civicrm/admin/setting/search?reset=1), and there is a dropdown for the Default Contact Search Profile, but my Search Views Profile does not show up in it.

It would be helpful if I could make my search view the default so that users do not have to select it each time they do a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you trying to use a profile which has Contact, Contact Type and Contact Sub Type Fields. The search preference allows you to choose profiles that have fields of contact and contact type. I have logged the issue at [CRM-21655](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21655). You can apply [patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11511) to make it work or wait for 4.7.31.

Comment: My pleasure. Cheerz

Comment: Hi Pradeep, I applied this patch and it was perfect! Many thanks.

Comment: Pleasure. Cheers